# RegEX in trimming first two character

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to extract two words from a line with regex using matcher in Java
my line goes like this, BROWSER=Firefox

I'm using the below code

```
currentLine = currentLine.trim();
System.out.println("Current Line: "+ currentLine);
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*?)=(.*)");
Matcher m = p1.matcher(currentLine);
if(m.find(1) && m.find(2)){
System.out.println("Key: "+m.group(1)+" Value: "+m.group(2));
}
```

The output I get is 
Key: OWSER Value: FireFox

BR is trimming off in my case. It seems to be weird to me, till I know why it behaves in this way, as this works perfectly with PERL. Can someone help me?

Comment: What's `currentLine`'s value? The one printed in `System.out.println("Current Line: "+ currentLine);`.

Comment: @AdrianWragg The (.*?) is unrelated, it just means a non-greedy match, which will make the regex engine stop at the first = sign rather than gobbling everything up and then backtracking. It's not strictly necessary in this case, but can be slightly more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `m.find(2)` it strips the first two chars. [From the JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) (bold is mine):

> `public boolean find(int start)`
>
> > Resets this matcher and then attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern, **starting at the specified index.**

So, use just `m.find()`:

```
String currentLine = "BROWSER=FireFox";
System.out.println("Current Line: "+ currentLine);
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*?)=(.*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(currentLine);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Key: "+m.group(1)+" Value: "+m.group(2));
}
```

Output:

```
Current Line: BROWSER=FireFox
Key: BROWSER Value: FireFox
```

[See **online demo** here](http://ideone.com/dxlXbV).

Comment: Perfect, this is the correct diagnosis and solution. The link to this form of find is this one though (it's just the next one on the page however): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28int%29

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) to find the location of the `=` and then [String.substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) to get your two values:

```
String currentLine = "BROWSER=Firefox";

int indexOfEq = currentLine.indexOf('=');

String myKey = currentLine.substring(0, indexOfEq);
String myVal = currentLine.substring(indexOfEq + 1);

System.out.println(myKey + ":" + myVal);
```